# Get the inner join query that is greater than the in value

Tags: php, mysql

I have a problem with SQL...

```
SELECT p.id,p.dosya_id,p.dosya_no,p.logo,p.islem,p.y_d_b_id,p.ulkeler,p.pat_adi,p.y_d_bas,p.kr_tipi,p.yurt_i_d,p.sinif_yazi,d.durum_id,d.i_id
FROM pat AS p INNER JOIN pat_dokuman AS d
ON p.dosya_id=d.dosya_id WHERE **d.i_id** IN(60,68,40) GROUP BY p.dosya_id
```

I want to get the `d.i_id` value.

Comment: use Max() you will get..

Comment: WHERE MAX('d.i_id') IN(60,68,40) use like this..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT max(p.id) ,
        p.dosya_id,
        p.dosya_no,
        p.logo,
        p.islem,
        p.y_d_b_id,
        p.ulkeler,
        p.pat_adi,
        p.y_d_bas,
        p.kr_tipi,
        p.yurt_i_d,
        p.sinif_yazi,
        d.durum_id,
        d.i_id 
FROM pat AS p
INNER JOIN pat_dokuman AS d 
    ON p.dosya_id=d.dosya_id 
WHERE d.i_id IN(60,68,40) 
GROUP BY p.dosya_id
```

Comment: you should add some explanations to make your answer useful for the others

Comment: No change ... again taking 40

Comment: Hi, 
I think something get understood wrong. I just want to list the progress id (d.i_id) 
It is required to list the big number is there is two record. For ex. There are two different numbers such as  60 and 40, I want to list the number 60. 
Accordingly, I appreciate your assistance in this matter.